# Elixir: How to test multiple values in case condition?

Tags: elixir

Is there a shorter way to write this:

```
case testvalue do
  200 ->
    true
  404 ->
    true
  _ ->
    false
end
```

It returns true for 200 or 404 and false for everything else. It would be nice to write it with an OR condition but this leads to an error:

```
case testvalue do
  200 || 400 ->
    true
  _ ->
    false
end
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

There's no direct syntax for `or` in the middle of patterns but you can use a guard:

```
case testvalue do
  n when n in [200, 400] ->
    true
  _ ->
    false
end
```

You can also use `or` in guards. This will work too but is more verbose:

```
case testvalue do
  n when n == 200 or n == 400 ->
    true
  _ ->
    false
end
```

Both will run equally fast as `in` inside guards is converted into comparisons + `or`, as mentioned in the [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Kernel.html#in/2-guards).

Comment: I believe this needs to be `n = testvalue when n in [200, 400] ->`, otherwise `n` is undefined

Comment: @Arijoon Seems to work fine for me; example I tested in `iex`: `f = fn x -> case x do n when n in [1, 2, 3] -> "1, 2, or 3"; _ -> "Other"; end end`.

Answer (score 5):

From my experience, it makes more sense in `elixir` to handle the cases with functions / pattern matching, it's more readable when your code base grows.

I would do something like that:

```rb
defp valid_http_response?(200), do: true
defp valid_http_response?(400), do: true
defp valid_http_response?(_), do: false
```

I agree it doesn't really make sense now, but in the future you will be happier :)

Answer (score 4):

For this specific case, perhaps returning the following would be best?

```
testvalue in [200, 400]
```

For example:

```
def test_my_value(testvalue), do: testvalue in [200, 400]
```

It will evaluate to `true` or `false` as intended.

Another possibility would be to use `cond`:

```
cond do
  testvalue in [200, 400] ->
    true
  true ->
    false
end
```

Comment: `cond` with `true ->` doesn't really work since I need the condition to return true OR false. How you wrote it the last condition will always match and thus the result will always be false.

Comment: The syntax looks slightly confusing in this case, but `true ->` is basically the equivalent of an "else" clause. See http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/case-cond-and-if.html#cond So the code above DOES return `true` or `false` as appropriate.